# How can you create a folder to store all your Lists in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In my Sharepoint Online site, I have a lot of Lists. I would like to put them all in a folder, kind of like a Document Library. How can I create a folder to put all these Lists in Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

You can't store them in a library, however you can create a new list that will contain a link to all of them and you can use this list a grouping method, if not, we will need to develop a custom component to group them.

Comment: I wanted to create a folder under Site Contents and place all the lists in that folder. I guess that is not possible.

Comment: I think it isn't possible yes,